# Can Turret Weapons be used to fire Overwatch if already engaged?

Tags: warhammer-40k

In Warhammer 40,000 9th Edition with the latest (2022) Astra Militarum codex, can a Turret Weapon be used to fire Overwatch if it is already engaged with an enemy unit?

Excerpt from the Overwatch rule:

> A unit cannot fire Overwatch if there are any enemy units within Engagement Range of it.

Excerpt from the Turret Weapon rule:

> If that model is within Engagement Range of any enemy units, it can still target and resolve attacks against enemy units that are not within Engagement Range of it with weapons with this ability.